# raw query sequelize node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I'm trying for a long time to do a raw query using sequelize. Following the guide on web, I write this piece of code:

```
 var sequelize = new Sequelize('name', 'user', 'password');
 var sql = '--query---';
 return sequelize.query(sql,  { raw: true });
```

But in this way, the number of results returned is not correct. Also, in a component, how can I manage the data returned?

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used to use this to select customers given a Stripe ID.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
           sequelize = new Sequelize('name', 'user', 'password', {
                   dialect: "mysql",
                   port: 3306,
           })

           var table = "users";

   sequelize
           .authenticate()
           .complete(function (err) {

                   sequelize.query(
                           "SELECT * FROM users WHERE stripe_id = :status ", null, {
                                   raw: true
                           }, {
                                   status: customer_id
                           }
                   ).then(function (myTableRows) {

                           // Query Response


                   });

           });
```

Personally I've moved away from sequelize to [RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com/) and am very happy. They have pretty in-depth javascript support.

https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/js/

Comment: Your solution generate "sequelize.authenticate(...).complete is not a function" error. ideas?